# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload information to my DB but it keeps giving me a syntax error.

`` $query = "INSERT INTO `klant` (`naam`,`adres`,`postcode`,`email`,`nieuwsbrief`) VALUES ($naam,$adres,$postcode,$plaats,$email,$nieuwsbrief)"; ``

The query I use should work as it's the same as in PHPMyAdmin.

The error I receive:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '4,1234AB,Rotterdam,email@gmai.com,1)'

Comment: Why are you passing an additional value to your SQL that you do not specify in the columns?

Comment: Your string values are not enclosed in quotation marks. That's an error already, but in this case it's complaining about a space in the `$adres` value. Use a prepared statement instead, that will also help with the sql injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two errors:

- There are five columns specified in your insert query, but you're trying to put in six values. They should match. (`plaats` is missing)
- String values should have quotes `""` around them in insert statements.

Also, rickdenhaan touched on a good point. Using variables like this is dangerous as it allows for SQL injection, especially if the variables are populated by the public.